# VBA Code: Value error with minimal function code (array input/output)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am still a newbee to VBA coding and have some rudimentary code to test for funcionality and then to expand it.

A certain code block seems to completely break the functionality (code works perfectly when I comment the block), although nothing much "happened" in the commented/uncommented code block.

```
Function Linearize(Old As Variant) As Variant

'    Dim R As Integer
'    Dim C As Integer
'    Dim L As Integer
'
'    R = UBound(Old, 1)
'    C = UBound(Old, 2)
'    L = R * C

    Dim NewA As Variant

    NewA = Old.Value2

    Linearize = NewA
    
End Function
```

When I uncomment the code block, the VALUE Error appears... "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type."

I just don't see WTF could have gone wrong? Help would be very much appreciated... Thank you so much!!

Comment: How did you load the `Old` array? Is it a 2D array? Which line raises the error? Is it `R = UBound(Old, 1)`? Is `Old` an array or a range? The `Variant` declaration accepts both cases. If an array `Old.Value2` does not make any sense. If it is an array, then `R = UBound(Old, 1)` is inappropriate... Please, edit your question and show us the Sub calling the function, too.

Comment: Is `Old` a range?  You use `Old.Value2` so I guess so.  What is in the cell(s) that you pass to the function?

Comment: Old has been defined as "Variant" (see upper line). .Value2 still works, even if it is not a range.
I tried different cell values (nums, fromulas, it doesen't matter, the works/doesn't work toggle ist the commented code block) for the cells that i pass to the function.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to solve your problem by remove wrong call:

```
Function linearize(old As Variant) As Variant

    Dim R
    Dim C
    Dim L As Integer

    R = UBound(old, 1)
    C = UBound(old, 2)
    L = R * C
    
    Debug.Print L


End Function
```

In another sub you can call the function

```
Sub test2()
Dim myarray(1 To 10, 50 To 100)

linearize (myarray)

End Sub
```